# How to do markererclusterer in android using both map apiv2 or map api v3

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

and do plz tell me the right emulator specification...
can it be error of emulator......

I have tried by following links

```
https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=iCf5Upm7KsWXrAedkoCoDg#q=marker+cluster+example+in+android
http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/04/clustering-on-google-map-v2.html
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204554/google-maps-marker-clusters-in-android
https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/
https://github.com/nodesagency-mobile/Android-Google-Map-V2-Sample
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/model
https://github.com/Bersh/MarkersCluster/blob/master/res/menu/activity_main.xml
https://github.com/damianflannery/Polaris/blob/clustering/sample/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/polarissample/util/Config.java
http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495171/cluster-markers-in-google-maps-android-v2/15510054#15510054
```

I am trying to build the app which need marker clustered so i have tried by so many times read the Google API create the demo but every time it show error  suggest me also that the web application is using map API v3 clustering the marker which API i have to used API v2 or apiv3 of map to build an app please help me out i am newbie at android 
or give me some link where i can found my solution

```
.............................mainactivity class..........................................

    package com.example.cluster;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    import com.example.demo.MarkerClusterizer;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
         private ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
            private Bitmap markerImage;
            private float oldZoom = 0;
            private GoogleMap map;
            private static final int INTERVAL = 25;
            private LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters;
            private final double initLat1 = 40.462740;
            private final double initLng1 = 30.039572;
            private final double initLat2 = 48.462740;
            private final double initLng2 = 35.039572;
            private static final int MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL = 4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            markerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            map= ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
             map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                LatLng position = new LatLng(initLat2, initLng2);
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL));
                map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                        if (cameraPosition.zoom != oldZoom) {
                            try {
                                clusters = MarkerClusterizer.clusterMarkers(map, markers, INTERVAL);
                            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        oldZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
                    }
                });
                createMarkers(map);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }


            private void createMarkers(GoogleMap map) {
                double initLat;
                double initLng;

                initLat = initLat1;
                initLng = initLng1;
                for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat + i, initLng + i);
                    markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
                }

                initLat = initLat2;
                initLng = initLng2;
                for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat + i, initLng);
                    markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
                }
                for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                    LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat, initLng + i);
                    markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
                }

            }
        }
...............................markerclusterizer class...............................
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MarkerClusterizer {
    private static GoogleMap map;
    private static int interval;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 25;


    public static LinkedHashMap<Point,ArrayList<MarkerOptions>>clusterMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap, ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return clusterMarkers(googleMap, markers, DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusterMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap, ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers, int i) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        map=googleMap;
        interval=i;
        Projection projection=map.getProjection();
        LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point> points=new LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>();
        for(MarkerOptions markerOptions:markers){
            points.put(markerOptions, projection.toScreenLocation(markerOptions.getPosition()));
            markerOptions.title("");

        }
        map.clear();
        CheckMarkersTask checkMarkersTask=new CheckMarkersTask();
        checkMarkersTask.execute(points);



        return checkMarkersTask.get();

    }

    private static class CheckMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>, Void, LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>>> {

        private double findDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
            return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
        }
        @Override
        protected LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> doInBackground(LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>... params) {
            LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters = new LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>>();
            LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point> points = params[0];
            for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : points.keySet()) { //go thru all markers
                Point point = points.get(markerOptions);
                double minDistance = -1; //Currently found min distance. This need for finding nearest point.
                Point nearestPoint = null; //Currently found nearest point
                double currentDistance;
                for (Point existingPoint : clusters.keySet()) {  //try to find existing cluster for current marker
                    currentDistance = findDistance(point.x, point.y, existingPoint.x, existingPoint.y);
                    if ((currentDistance <= interval) && ((currentDistance < minDistance) || (minDistance == -1))) {
                        minDistance = currentDistance;
                        nearestPoint = existingPoint;
                    }
                }

                if (nearestPoint != null) {
                    clusters.get(nearestPoint).add(markerOptions);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markersForPoint = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
                    markersForPoint.add(markerOptions);
                    clusters.put(point, markersForPoint);
                }
            }
            return clusters;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters) {
            for (Point point : clusters.keySet()) {
                ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markersForPoint = clusters.get(point);
                MarkerOptions mainMarker = markersForPoint.get(0);
                int clusterSize = markersForPoint.size();
                if (clusterSize > 1) {
                    mainMarker.title(Integer.toString(clusterSize));
                }

                map.addMarker(mainMarker);
            }
        }
    }
    }


  ![..............activity_main.xml...............................................
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <fragment 
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>t
    </RelativeLayout>
..................manifest.xml................................................
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cluster"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.cluster.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cluster.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDqFw-lJjvppil-ixpHjBolINPqJO2b83Q" />
    </application>

</manifest>][1]
```

Comment: API v2 is deprecated. What have you tried so far and what is the error that you get? Show us some code.

Comment: hello @MrUpsidown  I posted here what i have tried so far please see and give me sugeestion..

Comment: where i m doing the mistake

Comment: I can't test an android app. You said you were getting errors?

Comment: yes the error stack is posted above

Comment: plz check the code ....do tell me where i am getting an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I do so much R$D I found for single package name you have to generate single Api key for developing the map in android.
though i have done create 2 3 api key for different project with same package name.

Comment: but your main question was related for the emulator specification and how to do markererclusterer in android using both map apiv2 or map api v3.

Answer (score 0):

> do plz tell me the right emulator specification

I really like the `GenyMotion` to test my android application. It is much better than Android provides.

Download the Genymotion from [here](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/) and add the emulator whichever you want later

> error msg doesn't support opengles on device

and for the real device make sure your device support the OpenGL ES version 2 which your map required.

For the marker cluster you can read the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering).

Comment: @vaib I did not get you, explain a bit

Comment: kk i will send u the specification for that but plz see the whole question what i suppose to ask

Comment: For the marker clustering, read this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering If anything I left, you can ask here because your question seems almost unclear there

Comment: wut specification ? where have you attached?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48197/discussion-between-vaib-and-tgmcians)